# Make helm stop tracking namespace resource as part of the release, without actually deleting it

Tags: kubernetes-helm

In the company where I currently work we have RBAC Helm chart that is in-house developed that among other things has namespace resource in the template folder, thus the namespaces are now part of the Helm release.

We now realised that it is not such a good idea to include the namespace in Helm, because there may be number of cases (insert any reason here) where Helm may try to recreate given resource and if this happens on the namespace object it will delete (in order to recreate) the namespace along with everything in it.

My question: Is it possibly to make Helm stop tracking the namespace without actually deleting it, so that the namespace is no longer part of the Helm release?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `--namespace [namespace]` to your upgrade command, and simultaneously removing it from the chart? That should deploy the chart to the given namespace without tracking it through helm.

Answer (score 9):

As per Helm [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/), you can ask Helm not to delete the resource.

```
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/resource-policy": keep
```

*The annotation "helm.sh/resource-policy": keep instructs Helm to skip deleting this resource when a helm operation (such as helm uninstall, helm upgrade or helm rollback) would result in its deletion. However, this resource becomes orphaned. Helm will no longer manage it in any way. This can lead to problems if using helm install --replace on a release that has already been uninstalled, but has kept resources.*

Comment: NOTE: This would make the resource to be an orphan.